# Laravel, using AS does not pass on view side

Tags: php, laravel

I am try to get `count(message) As number` it looks like nothing wrong in controller side, but in view side, I am getting that error :

```
Error rendering view: [home.index]

Undefined property: stdClass::$number
```

My view side , I have code like that :

```
foreach($sorgu as $value)
{
    case 'BUL1':
    $sorgu99[0]+=$value->number;               
    break;
}

$posts = DB::table('xxx');

$posts = DB::table('xxx')->select( array('message', DB::raw('COUNT(message) AS number'), DB::raw('xxx.Time as time')));

$posts = DB::table('xxx')->join( 'xxs', 'xxx.smsCid', '=', 'rcs.smsCid', 'INNER');

$posts = DB::table('xxx')->where('xxs.status','=','1');

$posts = DB::table('xxx')->where( 'xxx.Time' ,'>', '2012-12-26');

$posts = DB::table('xxx')->where(DB::raw('length(message)'), '>', '3');

$posts = DB::table('xxx')->group_by('message');

$posts = DB::table('xxx')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Each time you call DB::table() you make a new query, so each line in your code above is making a new query, and in the end you're just getting all the posts from the xxx table.  Try this instead:

```
$query = DB::table('xxx');
$query->select( array('message', DB::raw('COUNT(message) AS number'), DB::raw('xxx.Time as time')));
$query->join( 'xxs', 'xxx.smsCid', '=', 'rcs.smsCid', 'INNER');
$query->where('xxs.status','=','1');
$query->where( 'xxx.Time' ,'>', '2012-12-26');
$query->where(DB::raw('length(message)'), '>', '3');
$query->group_by('message');
$posts = $query->get();
```

The database queries use method chaining.  If you want to read more about method chaining, ShawnMcCool wrote a good post about it: http://heybigname.com/2012/10/03/php-method-chaining/

Comment: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Comment: I would modify this to actually use method chaining. Also, this code does not belong in the view. It should be an a route, controller or composer.

Comment: @CollinJames I agree that the code does not belong in a view, I was aiming to fix the bug in the query.

Comment: @OnderOZCAN it is not possible for that error if you have copied the code correctly, as you would have a similar error on every other line.  Can you share what you have tried to code?